# C# & ServiceStack: Get Rest Body

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

I'm trying to write a Rest client using ServiceStack - so far I can successfully use GET to pull objects from my database and view them as JSON (I'm using RESTClient on Firefox to test my service). However, how would you go about updating or inserting to a database using REST? I've put info into the body section yet nothing happens in the database :S

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Actually I finally managed to get it, from the "Request" property and calling the .RawData () and deserialized it to the data transfer object... feel a bit stupid now for asking but ah well :)

Comment: You should be able to translate the dtos automatically. One of the benefits of servicestack. You might want to check out the Examples on github. https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples